# Video files from another partition or volume does not play

Tags: 12.04, video-player, codecs

Some video files from another partition or volume does not display in some video displays but display on another and crashes on others.

Seem to play on these video players:

- vlc
- smplayer
- gnome-mplayer

Seem to  have some issues in these video players:

> totem -some videos are play while others not banshee -some videos are
>   play while others not  bangarang -few videos are play while others not
>   and it crashes and happens also in home folder of filesystem dragon
>   player -crashes and seem not to display any video and happens also in
>   home folder of filesystem

**Why this happens? Is this a bug?**

This error occurs on ubuntu 12.04 beta 2.

On ubuntu 11.10, every video display play all the video from another partition or from home filesystem.

Comment: Totem and Banshee use a different media backend (gstreamer) than VLC and *mplayer, so it seems possible that you don't have all of the plugins installed for gstreamer.  Are you able to play other mp4 files (from your home folder) in Banshee or Totem?

Comment: yes. i can play other files in format mp4 using totem and banshee only on home folder

Answer (score 1):

I would not call such a thing a bug if I understood your question right.
Some media players just do not simply support all formats.
Some players support format A, B and C, while other C, D and E.

Your problem is with codecs.
You can download the package *non-free-codecs* which should solve the problem by

```
sudo apt-get install non-free-codecs
```

If it does not work, download [the following too](http://www.multimediaboom.com/top-10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-11-04-aka-natty-narwhal/):

```
sudo apt-get install libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder mpeg2dec vorbis-tools id3v2 mpg321 mpg123 libflac++6 ffmpeg libmp4v2-0 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 libjpeg-progs libmpcdec3 libquicktime1 flac faac faad sox ffmpeg2theora libmpeg2-4 uudeview flac libmpeg3-1 mpeg3-utils mpegdemux liba52-dev
```

Comment: the video format for all the video that i was playing is mp4 ..so i think is no due to the format of the video, but not sure.for example i played video1.mp4 but video2.mp4 not play and video3.mp4 also video4.mp4 play and so on(its an example)

Comment: The fact that the ending of the name is mp4 does not mean that the video is in the mp4 -format. So I think that is the problem. Another thing is that your videos may be corrupted.

Comment: they all play  with different player like vlc in ubuntu 12.04 beta!! and this files can be played on every player on ubuntu 11.10.i don't know if cause this videos are from youtube they must be same format,..t but i don know

Comment: Ok, so they are not corrupted. Ok, we need a tool that checks what is the format of your files. I need to think about the name of the terminal command for a while.

Comment: Please, run $file <mp4-file> to your files and let me know what you get.

Comment: 1.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2

Comment: 1.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2  all the files are that- i did in almost every file

Comment: Can you provide us sample files, please, like to Dropbox. It would make the thing a lot easier.

Comment: how do i send some example files ?what is dropbox?

Comment: @user49523 It is service to share files easily, please see https://www.dropbox.com/

Comment: here is the link to an compress file of some of those files: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70424606/videos.tar.gz

Comment: @user49523 Is there any way to get only one not working file, please?

Comment: this 2 files dont play at all :http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70424606/Relaxation%20Meditation%20%5BOcean%20Waves%20Crashing%20over%20a%20rock%5D.mp4 and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70424606/Whale%20Song.mp4 .

Comment: this file seems to play but don't play http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70424606/HD%20HAWAII%20BEACHES%20%2B%20Hawaiian%20Music%20Aloha%20Relaxing%20Ocean%20Sounds%20Romantic%20Songs%20video%20spa%201080p.mp4

Comment: for these files after coping 2 dropbox folder none thumbnails is showed but appear on www.dropbox.com with its thumbnails. for other files that display thumbnails are showed. this also seem to happen on the other volume what display is showed what not display don't

Comment: @user49523 I know where your problem is now. All the videos you pasted works with iMac OSX Lion: programs DoubleTwist, VLC player and QuickTime Player successfully. Phale and see -sound :) Your problem is with codecs. Please, see my updated post.

Comment: i run that on terminal and give me the following errors: 1)E: Unable to locate package non-free-codecs 2)E: Unable to locate package non-free-codecs

Comment: i think it is implicit that can not play on ubuntu 12.04, despite of also having ubuntu 11.10 installed, but i forget write that

Comment: @user49523 You can search the right codecs for instance from aptitude by *aptitude search [package]*. Another way is to use the graphical user interface and select to install proprietary updates from there. That should install those drivers to you also.

Comment: aptitude  graphical manager is currently not on the repositories but aptitude terminal is .. not sure if i am able to use that, not an expert

Comment: i was able to run aptitude terminal but didn't find any codec on category video on not installed

Comment: user49523 I will try the thing as soon as possible after my exams.

Comment: ok don't worry.i realize that  unselected this packages :E: Unable to locate package libmp4v2-0
E: Unable to locate package libmpcdec3
E: Unable to locate package libquicktime1
 could install the other codecs and it did but still videofiles don't work

Comment: i think i have to wait until ubuntu 12.04 final release so the repositories are all available good luck for your exams

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04beta2.

In 11.10 movie-player had no trouble playing mp4s dowloaded from youtube, however these will no longer play in 12.04beta2. This does *not* appear to be an obvious missing codec problem as I have all the codecs installed (and the files played OK before upgrade). The files will still play on 12.04 using mplayer and vlc.

The problem is present on multiple machines, both 32bit and 63bit.

Comment: i think we have to wait for the final realease of ubuntu 12.04 but not sure that the repositories will change but possibly